# Javascript Error when using UpdatePanel. ID is undefined Line 234437825

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I'm getting the following JavaScript error: `ID is undefined`.  My code isn't so big and I don't have more than 100 lines in my HTML script.  So I enabled debug mode in IE and when attempt to debug, it's going to `scriptresource.axd` and stopping at `ViewState`.  I'm using the update panel in my code.

The strange thing is that it does not stop any functionality.  All the functions are working.  I'm able to async a post back as well.

I tried to narrow down the problem, by removing my HTML code piecemeal.  By doing this, I found that the error is appears because of ScriptManager control.

I don't see any runtime exception from codebehind as well.

Has anybody got this error before?

Comment: It may be of some help if you share your code so there's some added context to what you're talking about.

Comment: meanwhile you post your source code can you do this if you are using dotnet framework 4 replace document.getElementById('YourId') with document.getElementById('<%=panelId.ClientId%>')

Comment: my js code looks like this

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
$("#lblSelectColumns").click(function() {
$("#divSelectColumns").slideToggle();
if ($("#lblSelectColumns").text() == "+ Select Columns") {
$("#lblSelectColumns").html("- Select Columns")
$("#divSelectColumns").removeClass('divSelectColumnSectionClose').addClass('divSelectColumnSectionOpen');
}
else {
$("#lblSelectColumns").text("+ Select Columns")
$("#divSelectColumns").removeClass('divSelectColumnSectionOpen').addClass('divSelectColumnSectionClose');
}
});

Comment: 'code'$(function(){$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkSelectAll").click(function() {
if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
$("[id*=chkSelectionColumns] input:checkbox").prop('checked', false);
}else {
$("[id*=chkSelectionColumns] input:checkbox").prop('checked', true); //To check all}
});}); 'code'